# How to get property from resource file dynamically?

Tags: c#

I need to get the localized description of enums. So I created a separate invariant `resx` file and set the Access Modifier to Public so that a `.cs` file is automatically generated. I also created localized resource files without code generation set.

I cannot use the `ResourceManager` class because the resource file will not create a satellite assembly. The generated file does have the property declared:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "17.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
public class CustomResource {
    
    private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
    
    private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;
    
    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    internal CustomResource() {
    }

    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyApp.Resources.CustomResource", typeof(CustomResource).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
    
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
        get {
            return resourceCulture;
        }
        set {
            resourceCulture = value;
        }
    }
    
    public static string Default {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("Default", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created this class:

```
public class LocalizedDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    private readonly string resourceKey;
    private readonly Type resourceType;

    public LocalizedDescriptionAttribute(string resourceKey, Type resourceType)
    {
        this.resourceKey = resourceKey;
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            //Get the property
            var property = resourceType.GetProperty(resourceKey, 
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            //Must have getter method
            if (property != null)
            {
                var propertyGetter = property.GetMethod;
                if (propertyGetter == null || (!propertyGetter.IsAssembly && !propertyGetter.IsPublic))
                {
                    property = null;
                }
            }

            return (string)property.GetValue(null, null)!;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I decorated my enums with the attribute:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [LocalizedDescription("Default", typeof(CustomResource))]
    Default = 0,

    [LocalizedDescription("Other", typeof(CustomResource))]
    Other = 1
}
```

However, the variable `property` in the `Description` method of the `LocalizedDescriptionAttribute` class is always null.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well what's been generated from the resource file? *Is* there a property called `Default` in `CustomResource`? Can you show us its declaration?

Comment: @JonSkeet Resource has been generated.

Comment: Okay, at this point I'd write an app which did *nothing* but fetch the property - don't do it with an attribute in an enum etc; just move the reflection code into your `Main` method, hard-coded to try to find `Default`. It *looks* like that should work... once you've managed to access the property in a simple Main method, you can go into the attribute side of things.

Comment: The property variable is still null.

Comment: That's odd. I've just tried to reproduce the problem, and it worked absolutely fine: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/8a63a404a2f3f8f5025d62f54dc3d55c - that's with a Resource1 resource. If you type `CustomResource` and then a period, does it prompt for "Default"? Is it possible that you've got multiple classes called `CustomResource`?

Comment: I solved it. CustomResource was also being used for `IStringLocalizer`. I created a separate reousrce file and it works as expected.